# Set of discontinuities is given by the set and closure problem

Tags: real-analysis

let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be any function. Let $D$ be the set of discontinuity point of $f$. Let $D(\epsilon)=\{x \mid \exists y_n \rightarrow x; \limsup|f(y_n)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$.

Show $D=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}D(\frac{1}{n})$ and $\overline{D(\epsilon)} \subset D(\frac{\epsilon}{2})$.

Since $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $y_n \rightarrow x \implies f(y_n) \rightarrow y$, $f$ is discontinuous at $x$ if $y_n \rightarrow x$ and $\limsup|f(y_n)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$. So for each point at which $f$ is discontinuous, choose an $\epsilon>0$ and $y_n$ satisfying the inequality. Let $C$ be the set of all such $\epsilon$. Since $\inf C \geq 0$ we see that $D=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}D(\frac{1}{n})$ since $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}D(\frac{1}{n})=\{x \mid \exists y_n \rightarrow x; \limsup|f(y_n)-f(x)|\geq 0\}$. Let $x \in \overline{D(\epsilon)}$. Choose a sequence $\{y_n\} \subset D(\epsilon)$ such that $y_n \rightarrow x$. Then for each $y_n$ there is a $z_{kn} \rightarrow y_n$ as $k \to \infty$ with $\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty}|f(z_{kn})-f(y_n)|\geq \epsilon$. Then $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty}(\lim\sup\limits_{k \to \infty}z_{kn}) \rightarrow x$ as $n \to \infty$. Then for fixed $n$, $$\epsilon \leq \limsup\limits_{k \to \infty}|f(z_{kn})-f(x)+f(x)-f(y_n)|\leq \\ \limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} |f(z_{kn})-f(x)|+\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty}|f(y_n)-f(x)|$$

Now if I can somehow show that $\limsup|f(y_n)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, the result will follow, however I think there might be some issues with the setup. Can I next take the $\limsup$ over $n$ and would this imply $\limsup|f(y_n)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon$. But what about the $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$?  Actually I realize there is a major issue with this, since I need to address whether I am taking the $\limsup$ over $k$ or $n$ in the string of inequalities. I know it would be a major issue if $z_{kn}$ does not converge to $x$ as $k \to \infty$ for some $n$ large. If this weren't true, my method of proof wouldn't work since I think it is implied I am taking the $\limsup$ over $k$ by the first inequality in the string. So I realize this is definitely going along the wrong route. Any suggestions on how to start the closure portion correctly?Also, is there any technical detail I am missing for the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have $\limsup|f(y_n)-f(x)| < \epsilon/2$, which is fine, or $\limsup|f(y_n)-f(x)| \ge \epsilon/2$, which is also fine. :-)